# temporary object, function parameters and implicit cast

Tags: c++

In the following scenario:

```
struct Foo
{
   // ...
   operator Bar() {... }  // implicit cast to Bar
}

Foo GetFoo() { ... }
void CallMeBar(Bar x) { ... }

// ...
CallMeBar( GetFoo() );
```

[edit] fixed the cast operator, d'oh[/edit]

`GetFoo` returns a temporary object of Type Foo. Does this object survive until after CallMe returns? What does the standard say?

I understand that if `CallMe` would accept  Foo, the temporary object would not be destroyed until after `CallMe` returns. I am not sure, however, fi the implicit cast changes this, and only the temporary `Bar` is guaranteed to survive.

---

A typical case would be Foo = CString, Bar = char *, i.e. Bar referencing data held by (and freed by) Foo.

Comment: Everything here is by value, is that intended or some references are involved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless of the cast, the temporary object(s) will "survive" the call to `CallMe()` function because of the C++ standard:

12.2.3 [...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the fullexpression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. [...]

1.9.12 A *fullexpression* is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression.

Answer (score 2):

It will survive, but relying in that fact may be confusing, and may cause clients of your code to reach for the C++ Standard, ask questions on Stack Overflow, etc ;-). For instance what happens when someone does:

```
Bar b = GetFoo();
CallMeBar(b);
```

This time, the Foo has gone before CallMeBar is called, but most programmers would want conversions to create an independent object, and hence for the code to behave the same as:

```
CallMeBar(GetFoo());
```

This is why `std::string` does not have an implicit cast to `char*`, unlike `CString`'s cast to `LPCTSTR`. Instead, `std::string` has the `c_str()` member function, which has the same constraint but makes it a bit more obvious in calling code that it's not a real conversion:

```
CallMePtr(GetString().c_str());   // OK

char* p = GetString().c_str();    // Bad
CallMePtr(p);                     // Badness manifests

const string &s = GetString();    // use "the most important const"
CallMePtr(s.c_str());             // Best be on the safe side
```

Comment: That first example is actually OK, isn't it? GetFoo() returns a Foo, which converts into a Bar, and is copied into the variable b. Then it lives happily ever after :)

Comment: Well, if the cast is a proper conversion, sure. But if CallMeBar relies on the the Foo still existing, which is what the OP is asking about, there's a problem. If the cast from Foo to Bar means that the resulting Bar is only valid as long as the Foo is, then I'm assuming the same is true of the copy. The model we're basing this on is the cast from CString to LPCTSTR, which I happen to think is a bad idea. It isn't really a conversion, it's an accessor to an inner component of CString.

Comment: Ah, I see. I interpreted Bar as a full-bodied value type all along, but that assumption isn't really supported by the code posted. Don't mind me :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you return them by value, they survive until CallMeBar is finished.

Your cast operator is a little off, though. Should be:

```
struct Foo
{
   // ...
  operator Bar() {... }  // implicit cast to Bar
}
```

See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A way I tend to think of it - the magic character is the semicolon. The semicolon triggers the destructors.