# Lifetime of implicitly casted temporaries

Tags: c++, casting, temporary, lifetime

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158084/temporary-object-function-parameters-and-implicit-cast).
It seems that regardless of the cast, the temporary object(s) will "survive" until the fullexpression evaluated.
But in the following scenario:

```
template<class T>
struct bar {
    T t;
    bar(T t) : t(t) {}
    template<class U>
    bar(bar<U> other) : t(other.t) {}
};
void foo(bar<const double&> b) {
    printf("%lf\n", b.t);
}
int main() {
    foo(bar<const double&>(2));//#1
    foo(bar<int>(2));          //#2
    return 0;
}
```

1 run well, but 2 do not.
And MSVC gave me a warning about 2: "reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits"

Now I am wondering why they both make a temporary `double` object and pass it to `bar<const double&>` and only 2 failed.

**@update**

I use struct bar instead of `boost::tuple` in the original post, hope it will be more familiar to others.

Let me make my question more clear. In #1, a temporal `double` is created from `int` (2) and then a `bar<const double &>` is created from it and copied into `foo`, while in #2, a temporal `bar<int>` is created and a temporal `double` is created from the member of `bar<int>` in the ctor of `bar<const double&>`. It seems that the temporal `double` is destructed in `foo` in #2 while do not in #1. Why? I think they are all part of the fullexpression and shall be exist until `bar` return.

Tim says "The compiler is smart enough to treat this 2 as a double instead of an int.". so I wrote `int i = 2;` and passed `i` to both of the two calls, but things go on like before. I made it in VS2008 with debug mode.

Comment: If less people could make edits at the same time to the source code (preferably letting the OP insert their exact source), that would really help people attempting to look at this question...

Comment: @KevenK: current source is exactly what the OP [tried to post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d2998079-6d12-4020-8f68-196a8a94ff55/view-source)

Comment: I'm so sorry about this...after I found some of the text don't show well, I edited several times. I never thought people here will help correcting my post so quickly. Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, g++ doesn't give any warnings about #2, even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (though it does give a warning about the `%lf` format specifier not being supported by ISO C++ -- just use `%f` instead).  But the output of the program is "2 0".

Comment: I don't have warnings under VS2005 with boost 1.45 either

Comment: @ybungalobill: Forgive my ignorance...what dose OP mean?

Comment: @icecrime: I use VS2008 with boost 1.45.

Comment: For the record, I would have said that #1 is wrong (temporary dies after the `tuple` construction) but #2 is correct (temporary dies at the end of the full expression). I'm not sure enough to expose myself to you downvoters :) Let's just wait for litb to stop by :p

Comment: @Answeror:  "OP" means "Original Post"    or   "Original Poster", depending on context. (Either the post itself, or the person who made the post)

Comment: Clang doesn't give any warning as well, but the ac tual behavior is weird: `-0.081821` for #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.#1 calls `boost::tuple<const double&>::tuple(const double&)`.  In order to do this, a temporary `double` is created by the full-expression `foo(boost::tuple<const double&>(2))`.   Then a temporary `boost::tuple<const double&>` is created.  It has a reference member which is bound to the temporary `double`.  Both temporaries exist until full-expression #1 is done, and is still valid when `foo` is called.

.#2 calls `boost::tuple<const double&>::tuple(const boost::tuple<int>&)`.  This expression creates a temporary `boost::tuple<int>`.   The lifetime of that temporary is similarly not a problem.  But consider what happens when that `tuple` constructor is called.  Simplified / pseudocode classes:

```
template<> class tuple<int> {
  private:
    int member1_;
  //...
};

template<> class tuple<const double&> {
  private:
    const double& member1_;
  public:
    tuple(const tuple<int>& int_tup) : member1_(int_tup.member1_) {}
  // ...
};
```

The mem-initializer `member1(int_tup.member1_)` converts the `int` value to a temporary `double` and binds that `double` to the class reference member.  This temporary `double` is created by the full-expression `member1_(int_tup.member1_)`, not by the full-expression `foo(boost::make_tuple(2))`.  A special exception for mem-initializers guarantees that the temporary `double` is okay until the end of the constructor in which it was created, but then there's no guarantee it's still valid when `foo` is called.

So the important difference is that statement #1 creates the temporary `double` itself, but statement #2 indirectly causes a temporary `double` to be created within another function.  Exactly *which* full-expression creates a temporary has an impact on how long that temporary will live.

Comment: Great! Now I understand it! Thank you and all the ones replied here!

Answer (score 1):

In #2, a temporal `tuple<double const&>` is constructed from `tuple<int>`
as the argument `n` for `foo`.
Before `tuple<double const&>`'s construction, a temporal double(D) is
constructed from an int member of `tuple<int>`, and the `double const&`
member is initialized as D.
Temporal objects constructed to prepare function arguments are destructed
when the function call is completed.
So, D is destructed when `tuple<double const&>`'s constructor finishes.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But in #1, a a temporal double is also constructed from int (2) then passed to a temporal `tuple<double const&>` and this temporal tuple is copied into foo, isn't it? So why temporal double in #1 wasn't destructed while in #2 do?

Comment: in #1, you're constructing a bar<const double&> from a literal `2`.  The compiler is smart enough to treat this 2 as a double instead of an int.  Thus, no temporal double like in #2.  If you created an actual `int i = 2`, and use `i` instead of `2` in #1, I believe you will see the same problem as #2

Answer (score 0):

I believe line #1 is OK because const references are allowed to refer to temporaries. Somebody can probably quote the standard on that.

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I am not a Boost or Tuple expert. I've never used either. I will attempt to be helpful anyway.

It appears to me that `boost::make_tuple(2)` is returning a `tuple<int>`. However, there appears to be an implicit cast done to match your `foo` implementation, during which time it may be attempting to take the address of the temporary (converting `int` to `const double&`) inappropriately.

Have you tried explicitly casting your `make_tuple`?

Again, I'm not a boost or tuple expert, but I would try:

```
 foo(boost::make_tuple(boost::cref((double)2)));//#2
```

or

```
 foo(boost::make_tuple((const double&)2);//#2
```

I admit I'm taking an educated guess here in an attempt to help, so I don't promise this is the right tree to bark up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code works well, but what I don't understand is that isn't the implicit cast part of the fullexpression? I means I think when "int" being casted to "const double&", it firstly be casted to a "double", and this "double" object order to live until the fullexpression evaluated.

Comment: I changed `boost::tuple` to a user defined struct.